# Laravel 'The requested URL was not found on this server.', but it exists on 'web.php'

Tags: laravel, apache, routes, docker-compose

Every time I try to access a route I get `"The requested URL was not found on this server."`, except for the `"/"` route. If I change some other route on `web.php` to be `"/"`, it works.

This is the `default.conf` for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName website-project
 DocumentRoot /var/www/website-project/public
 <Directory /var/www/website-project>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   Options -MultiViews -Indexes
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Handle Authorization Header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my url variable at `.env`:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

These are the routes at `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/create', [AppointmentController::class, 'newAppointment'])->name('appointment.newAppointment');
Route::post('/create', [AppointmentController::class, 'createAppointment'])->name('appointment.createAppointment');
Route::get('/edit/{appointment}', [AppointmentController::class, 'editAppointment'])->name('appointment.editAppointment');
Route::get('/', [AppointmentController::class, 'index'])->name('appointment.index');
```

I should note that I'm running the server on a `php:8.0-apache` container.

I tried:

- Activating `mod_rewrite`. It's apparently on.
- Removing and adding all `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in many permutations.
- Running `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` every time I made any change.
- Rebuilding the container many times.
- Changing moderation and ownership of all files.
- Changing the routes order and url, again, any will work if they use `"/"`.

Comment: Try changing the APP_URL to be `website-project`? Though you're missing the tld on your ServerName. It might be better to name it `website-project.local` and use that consistently, which will make it easier for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If there's someone out there struggling, I had to put
`RUN a2enmod rewrite | service apache2 restart` in the last line of apache's `dockerfile`, since running it in the container's bash wouldn't work because you need to restart the server, thus erasing the alterations.